# AngularJs controller and directive purpose, the right way?

Tags: angularjs

I've been reading up a more in depth about angularjs directive and controller, what should be in one and the other. The situation is this, I have multiple people with their types -> policemen, medicine, lawyers ... etc. inside the admin panel app, where the admin can manage them. In one section the admin can create, edit, delete them. The current versions controller does almost all the work: UI (bringing up the right form, hiding the other forms...), and logic (deleting, creating, updating methods for each person type). As I understand this is not good, because the controller does multiple things (no single responsibility). And even further the controller should only bind values to scope.

But does that mean, that I should only pull all the people (inside controller) and pass it some master directive which will manage it all? Or should their be more directives inside directives to divide the responsibility?

And if so, the controller will have to use the same service as the directive/directives. Controller for pulling people from back-end) and the directive/directives (for creating/updating/deleting) is this DRY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without code it's hard to give a precise answer, but the general idea when working with angular is this:

- Controller: The controller is responsible for keeping the views up to date with all the changes that are happening throughout your app. This means that it should **not** contain the business logic, this logic should instead be separated into small services. Each handling different parts of the logic for your app.
- Service: As stated above, a service should contain your business logic. Meaning that heavy calculations, manipulations etc. should be put into a service. Since services are singletons you can easily inject this service anywhere and re-use the logic within it, something you cannot do if you've put your logic inside a controller.
- Directives: Like controllers, directives shouldn't have any business logic in them. Directives are only there to create re-useable functionality as well as giving you a place to handle direct DOM changes. DOM changes should never be done anywhere but from within a directive.

To answer this:

> And if so, the controller will have to use the same service as the directive/directives. Controller for pulling people from back-end) and the directive/directives (for creating/updating/deleting) is this DRY?

If you have the data bound to a controller, you should not necessarily need a directive to handle the CRUD operations. Since the data is bound to the controller, you can easily create a template which reacts to the data changes automatically using `ng-repeat`, `ng-if` and so on.